# How to handle Web Workers "standard" syntax with webpack?

Tags: webpack, web-worker

I wonder if it's actually possible to handle Web Worker "standard syntax" in webpack (e.g `var worker = new Worker('my-worker-file.js');`) and how?

I know about [worker-loader](https://github.com/webpack/worker-loader) but as far as I understand it needs a specific syntax and is not compatible with the standard one.

In other words, is it possible to bundle that file with webpack without changing the code? -> https://github.com/mdn/simple-web-worker/blob/gh-pages/main.js#L8

With [browserify](http://browserify.org/), I would use [workerify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/workerify) transform, but I can't find anything in webpack's world.

Comment: you want to use webpack bundle but not its loader for handling the type of file?

Comment: I don't mind using a loader. But worker-loader would require to update the source code with a non-standard syntax. I'd rather find a solution that fits the standard Worker syntax and does not require to change the source.

Comment: Related : An interesting approach on how to _inline_ a worker, without using any webpack/browersify plugin : https://twitter.com/rauschma/status/820286148765425664

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can configure Webpack to pack your worker js file into a separate bundle. In `webpack.config.js`:

```
{
  entry: {
    bundle: './app/main.js',
    worker: './app/my-worker-file.js'
  },
  output: {
    filename: '[name].js'
  }
  ...
}
```

This way you get two bundles: `bundle.js` with your main application and `worker.js` with the worker entrypoint. Then, inside your main bundle, you can do `new Worker('worker.js')`

`worker-loader` basically does the same. Whenever something is loaded through it, it creates a separate bundle entry, so to speak, which is automatically named `[hash].worker.js`. It then stores this file name into the function that is returned from `require('worker!...')`, which just passes it to `new Worker`. At the end, it's exactly the same process as I've described above with the only difference that the name of the bundle is managed automatically for you.

Comment: I still find annoying that I need to reference the bundle name (`worker.js` in your example) instead of the source entry file (`./app/my-worker-file.js`). It creates a dependency between the source code and the webpack config that I was trying to avoid. Yet I think it's the best available solution for now, so thank for replying!

Comment: There is actually no problem in using any javascript file, even a self-standing file like `./app/my-worker-file.js`, say, by using `CopyWebpackPlugin` to deliver the file into the build directory. But if you're not using a bundle, then you're forfeiting the ability to `require` dependencies into your worker file.

Comment: By the way - avoiding a dependency between the webpack config and source is exactly what `worker-loader` gives you. If you don't want to explicitly write `require('worker!....')` in your source code (say, to avoid an explicit dependency on webpack), then you can simply configure webpack to use the worker loader: `module: { loaders: [ { test: /\.worker.js$/, loader: 'worker' } ] }`

Comment: or `... loaders: ['worker', 'babel']` if you're using e.g. babel.

Comment: I read about a new webpack plugin that seems to do exactly what I initially asked in that thread. I didn’t tested it yet, but probably worth a try for anyone confronted to this problem today. See https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/worker-plugin

Answer (score 2):

Since webpack5, webpack provides [the built in way of handling web work](https://webpack.js.org/guides/web-workers/) without `worker-loader`

Comment: This is what I used.  But of course it only became available recently.  At the time of the original question, this did not exist.